# Get scroll Position Percentage

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, panel

I need to be able to determine when the user has scrolled through 60% of the content in a panel and I'm not having much luck finding a solution for this.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Panel's [Scroll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.scroll.aspx) Event, you can do

```
double scrollPercentage = (double) 
                scrollbar.VerticalScroll.Value / scrollBar.VerticalScroll.Maximum;

if (scrollPercentage > 0.6)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: It is much more convoluted than that because of the thumb size.  Subtract LargeChange, add 1.  Or subtract 1, I forget.

Comment: Thanks @Hans Passant.  For anyone needing a more accurate solution, they should take your comment into consideration.  Bala's solution appears to be a good solution if you just need a rough percentage.