# How to get a control's location inside an autoscrollable panel? C#

Tags: c#, location, controls, autoscroll

C# : I have a panel (with Auto Scroll property true) on which I have many Picture Boxes. I need to get the Picture Boxes location relative to the panel's location. 
        I mean, when I scroll the panel, the Picture Boxes location changes, and I don't want that, I need the Picture Boxes location to remain constant whether I scroll the panel or not.
        What's the correct way to do that?

[panel with Picture Boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MedWb.png)

Comment: you can get the scroll value and calculate the position from that [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155389/get-scroll-position-percentage)

Comment: I tried that but i don't think i got it right because it doesn't work. I don't know how to add or drop the scroll value. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Nevermind, i got it right now. Thank you to you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there text that should be scrolling if the pictureboxes should remain on the samen location?

Can you clarify what the scrollbar should do ?

```
 Dim locX As Integer = PictureBox1.Location.X
 Dim locY As Integer = PictureBox1.Location.Y
 locX -=  Panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X
 locY -= Panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y
 TextBox1.Text = locX
 TextBox2.Text = locY
```

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/yGt28nD) In the Map Position groupbox, the X and Y textboxes contain the selected(the one colored with red) picturebox's location(which should be constant, they're read from a file and converted to display on the panel), but when i scroll the panel down or right(there are more pictureboxes there) the location of the selected pb changes. I need it to remain constant.

Comment: Ok mate , tested something out 
you should try to get your location by :

Dim locationX as Integer  = PictureBox.Location X -Panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X

Dim locationY as Integer  = PictureBox.Location Y -Panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y

locationX and locationY will give you the right location of the picturebox

Comment: This is exactly what i was doing right now, i got a hand of how to use the autoscroll position. Thanks very much tho.